# git re-commit all files

Tags: git, heroku

I have worked with two branches, master and v.2.0. I did allot of changes to v.2.0 and now I tried to push it to Heroku but nothing changed.

I have commited all files and now I cant push it to Heroku, because it says everything is up to date.

I have tried this command:

```
git push heroku v.2.0:master
```

I get this message

```
Everything up-to-date
```

What to do?

Comment: Since you're using branches, do you know about merging?

Comment: Yes I tried merging v.2.0 into my master, but the same message i show'v when i try to add and commit files

Comment: It looks like you've already merged (and `git merge` automatically commits). Can you make sure that `git log master` contains your v0.2 changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to trust Git that everything is up-to-date. Are any commits returned by `git log master..v.2.0`?

If you merged `v.2.0` into `master`, it seems likely that they both refer to the same commit.

Comment: No nothing is returned? Why cant I just re-submit everything?

Comment: You could try a `git push -f heroku master`, but I doubt it would change anything - it sounds like your v.2.0 changes are already live. Try making another trivial commit and pushing?